# React how when to use key in reduce method

Tags: reactjs

For this example do I need to put a key for the fragments created in either in the `map` function or the `reduce` function? I am not getting any errors in the console. If so what would the key be? These are just strings and could be quite long. I could use array index but React says not to.

```js
<article>
  {children
    .split(searchTerm)
    .map((item) => <>{item}</>)
    .reduce((acc: React.ReactNode, curr: React.ReactNode) => (
      <>
        {acc}
        <HighlightedText>{searchTerm}</HighlightedText>
        {curr}
      </>
    ))
  }
</article>
```

Comment: in this case I think you can use the index as key since there is no available unique IDS

Comment: In the reduce function only, correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If items in your rendered list have an unique ID property, then always use that as `key`. Alternatively, you can use `index` as the `key` if:

1. The list is a static list and will not change, e.g. you are never adding items to the list or removing items from it
2. The list will never be reordered or filtered, e.g. you are never sorting based on a column value or filtering based on user inputs

You could use `React.Fragment` inside `map` and pass keys using the approach below (for example):

```
import React from 'react';

const ITEMS = [{id: "one", title: "title one", description: "description one"},
 {id: "two", title: "title two", description: "description two"},
 {id: "three", title: "title three", description: "description three"}]

export function App(props) {
  return (
    <div className='App'>
     {ITEMS.map((item)=>
        <React.Fragment key={item.id}>
           <h1>{item.title}</h1>
           <h3>{item.description}</h3>
         </React.Fragment>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```